# Integration Problem? Rotated Hexagon

Tags: integration

We have $2$ vertices of a regular hexagon: $(8,0)$ and $(16,4)$. Let $X$ denote the maximum possible volume of the solid formed by rotating this hexagon about the $y$-axis. Compute $X$.

Does this have to do with integration? If so, please provide an integration solution and a solution that doesn't entail integration.

Comment: Have you found the hexagon that will give the maximum volume by this rotation?

Comment: Yes $120\sqrt{3}$

Comment: See:    https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem

Comment: I found the distance that the centroid travels - $16\pi$. Now what should I do? Is the answer $120\cdot16\pi\cdot\sqrt3$?